# Why does this record typecheck?

Tags: haskell, record

Given a datatype

```
data Foo = Foo { one :: Int, two :: String } deriving (Show)
```

An incomplete expression passes typechecking -- e.g.

```
foo :: Foo
foo = Foo { one = 5 }

main = print foo
```

Typechecks (emitting a warning about the incomplete record), then (obviously) crashes when the expression is encountered. Why does it pass? Without record syntax it doesn't (i.e. `bar = Foo 5 :: Foo`).

Comment: Because the language allows incomplete record instances. Use compiler warnings to help you here with possibly warnings as errors.

Comment: @ThomasEding: but then shouldn't `foo :: String -> Foo`?

Comment: @amindfv: No.  `foo` is a record of type `Foo` but its second field, and hence`two Foo`, is undefined.  You're probably thinking about partial application, but unfortunately Haskell's `{}` for records is just syntax and not a "first-class" language feature, so this doesn't work.  Check out the `lens` package or similar if you want first-class record updates.

Comment: @Fixnum: right, I'm thinking that `Foo { one=5 }` is equivalent to `Foo 5`. Why is it not implemented like this?

Comment: The record syntax is basically a hack to reduce the verbosity of _updating_ some fields from a large datatype.  Many people consider this a not-so-great part of Haskell, and the "lens" family of packages (`lens`, `data-lens`) are designed in part to improve this situation by giving you composable accessors and updates.

Comment: (What I said above isn't complete -- it's obviously useful for _creating_ records as well as updating them.)  As to why it wasn't implemented the way you suggest, I don't know. What would you like `Foo { two = 6 }` to desugar to?

Comment: @Fixnum: I think it would make more sense to desugar to `\i -> Foo i 6 :: Int -> Foo`

Comment: That goes rather beyond the initial analogy with partial application.  Also, part of the point of record syntax is making it more convenient to work with datatypes having more than just one or two fields.  Let's say you initialize two out of of eight fields in a large datatype.  While you could have this mean an anonymous function of six parameters, this loses the benefits (field naming) of record syntax in the first place.  Now you probably want to have `{ bar = baz }` passed to this anonymous function just "do the right thing", suggesting a function isn't the right representation...

Comment: This is what `lens` and its simpler competitors solve, and more besides.

Comment: @Fixnum: I think the analogy to partial application is straightforward -- it's just unordered. `Foo { one=4 }` is equivalent to `\s -> Foo 4 s :: String -> Foo`. The unordered nature is what makes record syntax nice, IMO.

Comment: My point was that the function `\s -> Foo 4 s` loses this 'unorderedness', which is especially annoying for larger numbers of fields.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Haskell 2010 report says in section [**3.15.2 Construction Using Field Labels**](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-520003.15.2)

> A constructor with labeled fields may be used to construct a value in which the components are specified by name rather than by position. Unlike the braces used in declaration lists, these are not subject to layout; the { and } characters must be explicit. (This is also true of field updates and field patterns.) Construction using field labels is subject to the following constraints: [...]
>
> - Fields not mentioned are initialized to ⊥.
> - A compile-time error occurs when any strict fields (fields whose declared types are prefixed by !) are omitted during construction.

So it's part of the language specification and a compiler must accept the code. All fields are initialized, just some are initialised with `undefined`.

```
foo = Foo{ one = 5 }
```

is equivalent to

```
foo = Foo 5 undefined
```

A nice compiler will warn you about it if you ask it to. If you want an error, make the fields strict.

Comment: And the reason is so that you could write e.g. `main = print $ one foo` without needing to define what's not referenced?

Comment: I can only speculate about the reason. But I guess it's along those lines, so you can use big records without mentioning all fields all the time.

Comment: it allows you to chain definitions.  You can write functions that partially defining records and chain them together.  This is actually really nice.

Comment: @PhilipJF For this purpose, this undefined'ness would not be strictly needed. One could have a "model" record and use it as starting point for construction.